# hyper link button Target __blank not working while click image within repeater control

Tags: asp.net

My asp code like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="imgbtnHl" runat="server" Target="_blank"> // hyper   link btn am givem target equal to blank but it is not working/ 
      <asp:ImageButton runat="server" Width="300px"ID="imgbtnHospitalimg" ImageUrl=images/tt.png" />/while click the image i want new window not an popup/
 </asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Did you set NavigateURL property? Without that you cannot navigate to other page.

Comment: ya am Navigating code behind file like Response.Redirect("../test.aspx",false);

Comment: Response.redirect is different thing. You need to set navigateURL for hyperlink so that when you click on that it will open that url in new tab.

Comment: i did that one also not working like      <asp:HyperLink ID="imgbtnHl" runat="server" Target="_blank"  NavigateUrl="~/test.aspx">

Comment: `<asp:ImageButton runat="server" Width="300px"ID="imgbtnHospitalimg" ImageUrl=images/tt.png" /></asp:HyperLink>` Have tried this missing hyperlink tag

Comment: So your hyperlink looks good. What happens when you click on that?

Comment: Lets discuss in chat if you still didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use image button inside hyperlink instead of that use simple img tag.
referrer below code i have tested working fine.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" Visible="true">
            <ItemTemplate>

       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="~/Default3.aspx" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'><img src="Good-mark.png" /></asp:HyperLink>

 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```